# Multiple Rolling Regression (Fama-Macbeth Procedure)

Tags: r, linear-regression, na, rolling-computation

## Introduction to the problem

**Hello everyone,**

I'm currently doing my thesis using the famous Fama-Macbeth rolling windows procedure to estimate a model with many independent variables and with an unbalanced panel data. Will do a comparison with different multi-factor models. Here I ask for the complete one (8 factors) since the complete code will be used as a reference for smaller models.

The problem arises just here, since many tutorials on the web deal with rolling regressions but very few show it in a multiple regression fashion. My knowledge of coding is for now not sufficient to set up such a problem without having enough reference on previous examples. 
Moreover, in case anyone knew Python better, I would also highly appreciate a Python version of this code.

I researched many similar problems, but apart for one, I couldn't find something properly applicable to my data. It seems that one of the fastest ways was to use matrix algebra or "rollRegres". Well, the "rollRegres" version worked out properly up to the point where my data displayed missing values (blank cells) transformed into "NA" automatically. However, these missing data display different issue dates by different securities, meaning that no action shall be taken with these missing cells.

Therefore, if anyone knew how to speed up this code (being far from efficient in the case of larger datasets), propose something else, or properly show me how to do it in a matrix form, I would heartily appreciate.

**Summarizing:**

- Rolling regression (8 ind. + 1300 dep. var's with window 60 days) - need betas

  > - Large dataset "Y" (1.300 dep. var's each with 1000s of entries)
  > - Dataset "X" (8 ind. var's - factors - all with 1000s of entries)
- Any possibility to make it robust (replaced lm() with rlm() of library MASS without success)
- NAs in the dataset "Y" due to different issue dates (data peculiarity)
- Efficiency (speed issues)
- Output (exporting issues)

## Code

A fair reproduction of my dataset is as follows. Bear in mind that the original dataset is much larger, and a code like that would be far from being efficient.

```
###LIBRARIES
library(zoo)


###DATASET

set.seed(10000000)

df <- data.frame(

##Date
Date = seq(as.Date("2000/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 5000),  

##Factors (indep var)
MKTRF = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),
SMB = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),
HML = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),
RMW = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),
CMA = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),
MOM = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),
TERM = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),
DEF = sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE),

##Securities (dep var)
#type 0
B1 = c(rep(NA, 1000), sample(1:100, 3000, replace=TRUE), rep(NA, 1000)),
B2 = c(rep(NA, 1500), sample(1:100, 3000, replace=TRUE), rep(NA, 500)),
B3 = c(sample(1:100, 3000, replace=TRUE), rep(NA, 2000)),
B4 = c(rep(NA, 1000), sample(1:100, 4000, replace=TRUE)),
B5 = c(sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE)),

#type 1
GB1 = c(rep(NA, 1500), sample(1:100, 2000, replace=TRUE), rep(NA, 1500)),
GB2 = c(rep(NA, 1500), sample(1:100, 3000, replace=TRUE), rep(NA, 500)),
GB3 = c(sample(1:100, 3000, replace=TRUE), rep(NA, 2000)),
GB4 = c(rep(NA, 1000), sample(1:100, 4000, replace=TRUE)),
GB5 = c(sample(1:100, 5000, replace=TRUE)))


###REGRESSION

#Setting the problem
z <- read.zoo(df, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
View(z)

getCoef <- function(z, lhs, rhs) {
  if (all(is.na(z[, lhs]))) "Empty"         #"Empty" is for me to spot empty cells due to different issue dates
  else coef(lm(paste(lhs, "~", rhs), z))
}

roll <- function(z, lhs, rhs = "MKTRF + SMB + HML + RMW + CMA + MOM + TERM + DEF") {
  rollapplyr(z, 60, getCoef, by.column = FALSE, coredata = FALSE, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs)
}

ynames <- c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "GB1", "GB2", "GB3", "GB4", "GB5")

#Regress
L <- lapply(ynames, roll, z = z)

#Save outputs
output <- Map(fortify.zoo, L)
```

This code, from a similar problem on Stack-Overflow, works but shows a little issue in the output (will become clear with the screenshot - pyramidal results in the first rows of data). Moreover, it is absolutely not efficient for long datasets. Finally, I would like to export all betas for each security in a clear and concise manner (in this case B1:GB5); now these remain in the list "output"; preferably in a table to open with notes.

If anyone would be so kind as to propose any type of improvement, this would really be much appreciated. Moreover, I think this may remain a solid reference for others dealing with such type of regression.

[Image - Pyramidal_outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rIJB.png)

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: I have no clue what kind of day that is, but I’d suggest editing it out @Newby

Answer (score 1):

We can make a few improvements:

- use matrices X and Y
- for each subset we can regress all the Y columns at once reducing the number of calls to the regression function by an order of magnitude
- handle NA errors
- rollapply over the index rather than over the data
- use .lm.fit instead of lm
- reshape result into a 3d array

This results in the following code.

```
library(zoo)

nr <- nrow(df)
X <- cbind(1, as.matrix(df[2:9]))
Y <- as.matrix(df[10:19])

coef_fun <- function(ix) {
  co <- try(coef(.lm.fit(X[ix, ], Y[ix, ])))
  if (inherits(co, "try-error")) NA else c(co)
}
out <- rollapplyr(1:nr, 60, coef_fun, fill = NA)

out <- array(out, c(nr, ncol(X), ncol(Y)), 
  dimnames = list(NULL, colnames(X), colnames(Y)))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Grothendiek but this seems not to be the right answer. As I specified, removing NA will cause the dataset to restrict considerably (in this case from 5.000 to 1.500 observations), something which should not be done. Anyhow, I appreciate the answer because it gives me insights on how to speed up such a process in case I had no NA in the data or when I could deal with these.

Comment: Have modified to not remove NAs.  Instead individual coef_fun runs return NA if .lm.fit issues an error on a particular subset.  You will still see the error messages but it will continue running anyways.